# Methods to produce solvable deals in Klondike-solitaire?

Tags: solvability

About 20% of [Klondike-solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire)) deals are not solvable. My question is what are the best methods to produce only solvable deals?

I thought about two options:

1. Deal a random permutation, then try to solve it with a solver, if failed, re-deal. (requires a solver like ‘Solvitaire’)
2. Go back from the winning state, use random reverse moves until we get to a starting state. (needs a tool that produce random reverse-moves)

*This question might be better suit in a different Q&A site, please let me know if that is the case.

Paper that describe the Solvitaire solver: [The Winnability of Klondike Solitaire and Many Other Patience Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire))

[image]

Comment: Welcome to PSE! A link or a short summary of the rules would help.

Comment: @melfnt, Tnx, added a link

Comment: I think you've pretty much answered you own question - those two methods should work quite well.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, maybe you have incites about the pros and cons of those two options? What do you think I should choose between those two?

Comment: The first option seems the easiest to implement. The second option requires some actual coding and thinking about reversal of moves. Perhaps some moves are not easy to reverse.